# SQLite database is empty after first loading

Tags: android, sqlite

When I create my db and insert some items inside and after that I try to read it it is empty, but this is only in first start of my app, is there anyway to refresh the db or reload it after insert the new item. I want to read from it from my first start, not from the second.

Here is my code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    protected SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBConstants.DB_NAME, null, DBConstants.DB_VERSION);
        open();
    }

    public void insertMuseum(Museum museum) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ID, museum.getId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_URL, museum.getImageURL());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_DESCRIPTION, museum.getDescription());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_LOCATION, museum.getLocation());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_NAME, museum.getName());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_STATUS, museum.getMapStatus());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_SIZE, museum.getMapSizeKB());

        database.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MUSEUMS, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertRoom(Room room) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ID, room.getId());
        for (Door door : room.getDoors()) {
            cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_DOORS, door.getConnectedTo());
        }
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, room.getMapId());
        for (QR qr : room.getQrs()) {
            cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_QRS, qr.getId());
        }
        for (MapPoint point : room.getShape()) {
            cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_SHAPE, point.getX());
        }
        database.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_ROOMS, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertMap(MuseumMap map) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ID, map.getId());
        for (Room room : map.getRooms()) {
            cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, room.getId());
        }
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MUSEUM_ID, map.getMuseumId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ENTRANCE_ROOM_ID, map.getEntranceRoomId());
        database.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MAPS, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertDoor(Door door) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_CONNECTED_TO, door.getConnectedTo());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_X, door.getX());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_Y, door.getY());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, door.getMapId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, door.getRoomId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ID, door.getId());
        database.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_DOORS, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertShape(MapPoint point) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_X, point.getX());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_Y, point.getY());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, point.getMapId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ID, point.getId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, point.getRoomId());
        database.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_SHAPE, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertQr(QR qr) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ID, qr.getId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_INFO, qr.getInfo());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_X, qr.getX());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_Y, qr.getY());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, qr.getMapId());
        cv.put(DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, qr.getRoomId());
        database.insert(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_QRS, null, cv);
    }

    private void open() {
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(createMuseumTable());
        db.execSQL(createMapTable());
        db.execSQL(createRoomsTable());
        db.execSQL(createQrsTable());
        db.execSQL(createDoorsTable());
        db.execSQL(createShapeTable());
    }

    private String createDoorsTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_DOORS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_CONNECTED_TO + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_X + " REAL, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_Y + " REAL);";
    }

    private String createShapeTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_SHAPE + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_X + " REAL, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_Y + " REAL);";
    }

    private String createRoomsTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_ROOMS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_DOORS + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_SHAPE + " REAL, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_QRS + " TEXT);";
    }

    private String createMapTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MAPS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MUSEUM_ID + " INT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ENTRANCE_ROOM_ID + " TEXT);";
    }

    private String createMuseumTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MUSEUMS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ID + " INT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_URL + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MAP_STATUS + " INT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MAP_SIZE + " INT);";
    }

    private String createQrsTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_QRS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_INFO + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_X + " REAL, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID + " TEXT, "
                + DBConstants.KEY_Y + " REAL);";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MUSEUMS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MAPS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_ROOMS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_QRS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_DOORS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBConstants.DB_TABLE_SHAPE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void museumStatusUpdate(int museumId, int mapStatus) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_STATUS, mapStatus);
        database.update(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MUSEUMS, values, DBConstants.KEY_ID + "=" + museumId, null);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(String tableName) {
        String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + tableName;
        Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery(count, null);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        int iCount = mCursor.getInt(0);
        mCursor.close();
        return iCount <= 0;
    }

    public void close() {
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor getShapeValues() {
        return this.database.query(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_SHAPE, new String[]{
                        DBConstants.KEY_X, DBConstants.KEY_Y, DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, DBConstants.KEY_ID},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getDoorValues() {
        return this.database.query(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_DOORS, new String[]{DBConstants.KEY_CONNECTED_TO,
                        DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, DBConstants.KEY_ID, DBConstants.KEY_X, DBConstants.KEY_Y},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getQrValues() {
        return this.database.query(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_QRS, new String[]{DBConstants.KEY_ID,
                DBConstants.KEY_INFO, DBConstants.KEY_X, DBConstants.KEY_Y, DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID,
                DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getMuseumValues() {
        return this.database.query(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MUSEUMS, new String[]{DBConstants.KEY_ID,
                DBConstants.KEY_DESCRIPTION, DBConstants.KEY_LOCATION, DBConstants.KEY_MAP_STATUS,
                DBConstants.KEY_NAME, DBConstants.KEY_MAP_SIZE, DBConstants.KEY_URL}
                , null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getRoomValues() {
        return this.database.query(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_ROOMS, new String[]{DBConstants.KEY_ID,
                DBConstants.KEY_DOORS, DBConstants.KEY_MAP_ID, DBConstants.KEY_SHAPE,
                DBConstants.KEY_QRS}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getMapValues() {
        return this.database.query(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_MAPS, new String[]{DBConstants.KEY_ID,
                DBConstants.KEY_ROOM_ID, DBConstants.KEY_MUSEUM_ID, DBConstants.KEY_ENTRANCE_ROOM_ID}
                , null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

The problem is here whe I try to call cursor.moveToFirst() :

```
public void loadMuseumsList(final DownloadListener listener) {
        Cursor cursor = dbUtils.readMuseumRecord();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Museum museum = new Museum();
                museum.setImageURL(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_URL)));
                museum.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_DESCRIPTION)));
                museum.setLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_LOCATION)));
                museum.setMapSizeKB(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_SIZE)));
                museum.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_ID)));
                museum.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_NAME)));
                museum.setMapStatus(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.KEY_MAP_STATUS)));

                if (!duplicateCheck(museums, museum)) {
                    museums.add(museum);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        listener.onMuseumListDownloaded(museums);
    }
```

It just return false.

And before this method I am loading the db from here:

```
public void downloadMuseumsList(final DownloadListener listener) {
        final boolean isEmpty = dbUtils.isEmpty();
        fireBaseRef.child("museums").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<Museum> museums = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot postMuseum : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Museum museum = postMuseum.getValue(Museum.class);

                    if (!duplicateCheck(museums, museum)) {
                        museums.add(museum);
                        dbUtils.writeMuseumRecord(museum);
                    }
                }
                if (isEmpty){
                    listener.onMuseumListDownloaded(museums);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, firebaseError.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

this is wehre I am writing my records after the downloading, but the db is empty after that and after I restart the app the db is ok.

Comment: The class above looks okay what about the class which is calling the same?

Comment: I am loading data from online database and write it inside my db, just a sec now i will post the code.

Comment: I uploaded the rest of my code which loading this db

Comment: This looks okay too. Please confirm if you are performing the insert query to db before using it anywhere else

Comment: when I call this method `dbUtils.writeMuseumRecord(museum);` it actually using this one `insertMuseum(Museum museum);`

Comment: but when I try to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` for the very fisrt time it is false

Comment: Ohhh check for the query in that case

Comment: What do you mean, this is my first database so sorry about that question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution! The problem was that I am recording in the DB asynchronous and the code going on and the db is really empty :)

I changed this and all is ok now:

```
public void loadContent(final DownloadListener listener) {

        if (dbUtils.isEmpty()) {
            FireBaseLoader.getInstance(context).downloadMuseumsList(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMuseumListDownloaded(List<Museum> museums) {
                    loadMuseumsList(listener);
                }
            });
        } else {
            FireBaseLoader.getInstance(context).downloadMuseumsList(listener);
            loadMuseumsList(listener);
        }
    }
```